# How can I define VS Code snippets in a .code-workspace file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-workspace

If I add a section `"code-snippets"` to `"settings"` in the `.code-workspace` file it is all greyed out "Unknown configuration". [The documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets) is not very helpful here.

[image]

Comment: where in the docs do they mention you can store snippets in a `settings.json` file or section

Comment: @rioV8 Not but I would like to put them there and not in the `.vscode` folder and hence reduce the number of configuration files to maintain. I've moved the `.vscode/tasks` to `settings.json` and guessed that along the same lines also snippits could be handled that way. Probably wrongly.

Comment: I am prompted with `"[snippets]"` by autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware, VS Code does not support specifying snippets in a `.code-workspace` file. Historically related is [Feature Request - Project-level extensions and snippets #8102](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/8102), but it seems they just added support for `.vscode/*.code-snippets`, but not a member in the `.code-workspace` schema. You could [raise a feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for them to add that.